significance of an observation in a small sample
In a population of 10000 individuals, I test 30 individuals and find that all of them have a disease. Based on this sample size, can I carry out some statistical test to find what proportion of the population might have this disease, given that all the 30 individuals tested have the disease?
I am getting tests like Cochrane's test to find a sample size for a given significance but I am unable to find an exact solution for my question above

In order to test statistical significance, you need a statistical null hypothesis (something like "no effect"). I don't see what that could be here. The term "significance" does not apply in the way you seem to mean it in "significantly present in the population". (One could test whether the proportion of people having the disease in the population could be 0.5 or significantly more, but that doesn't seem to make much sense here.) Of course the disease is "present" in the population if you have seen 30 individuals that have it; the term "significant" doesn't add anything to that.

Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "significantly present in the population"; but avoid the word 'significantly'. Indeed, ideally avoid statistical jargon as far as possible and explain in the plainest words you can.

Thank you very much for your suggestions. I have edited the question.

How were the 30 individuals selected? If a random sample of the 10,000, you can compute a confidence interval for the ratio 30/10000. If not a random sample, you can't really say anything

"find what proportion of the population might have this disease" - that's not the job of a test, rather of an estimator (more information about uncertainly is in a confidence interval). See answer of @rolando2.

Yes. The 30 individuals were selected at random. Thank you for the detailed guidance!

See the Rule of Three.

Based on Regression and Other Stories by Gelman, Hill and Vehtari, p. 52, one can create a corrected confidence interval as follows.
Estimate the probability of disease, p_hat, using (y+2)/(n+4) where y is the number of diseased observations.  This yields 32/34 = .941.
Use a standard error of sqrt(p_hat[1-p_hat]/[n+4]) = sqrt(.941[.059]/34) = .040.
A 95% confidence interval thus becomes .941 +/- 1.96*.040 = [.863,1] (since we truncate it at 1).

this assumes the 30 tested individuals were randomly selected. If they were selected for some reason, then the confidence interval won't be meaningful.

Since it's a medical test, shouldn't we take into account the test sensitivity and specificity? That would be interesting to address, though that's an information missing in the question.

What you are asking for is a confidence interval (CI) of a binomial proportion. This will give you an interval for the true proportion $p$ of the variable, based on the observed proportion $\tilde p$. Furthermore, since you observed 30 out of 30, you are really only interested in the low bound, and thus should use a single sided CI (the upper bound will always be 1, in your case, as $\tilde p=1$).
Now, this is a very well studied topic, and there are many methods to compute such a CI. You may want to look up wikipedia (which lists many of them) or this paper, which compares 13 such methods, or look on CV for many such questions, including this one, which is closer to your scenario.
Now, not surprisingly, just as there are many methods, there are also many, sometimes quite passionate, proponents of a given method over another. So be ready to hear diverging opinions.
Note that many methods rely on normal approximations to the binomial distribution. But in your case ($\tilde p=1$, or for that matter $\tilde p=0$), the normal approximation is very poor. So simple methods, such as the Wald interval, which is not great in general (but convenient), becomes unusable in your scenario.
A method which does not assume normality is the Clopper-Pearson interval. In your case it gives you an interval of [.905,1].
Agresti-Coul is a normal method with better behavior than Wald, which gives an interval of [.9014,1].
The "rule of 3" (mentioned by @whuber) gives [.9,1], while the Wilson score gives [.9173,1].
All the above were computed with $\alpha=.05$ (tradition). As you can see, the results are close, but not identical. There is also a Baeysian method (Jeffreys interval), which has good frequentist properties.
I personally would use Clopper-Pearson, but some (many?) object to it being too conservative (as described by Wikipedia: "Thus the interval may be wider than it needs to be to achieve 95% confidence, and wider than other intervals."). However, as you can see from the few methods I computed (and some mentioned in other answers), it is certainly not the widest interval, at least not in your case (Clopper-Pearson's coverage depends on specifric values of $n$, and $p$).
Now, all of the above rests on the assumptions that a) the 30 subjects were taken at random b) all 30 are true positives (i.e. the test you used to diagnose them did not give you some false positives).
Edit 10/28/24 - In response to @whuber's comment
@whuber questioned the decision to use a single-sided test “post-hoc” (after seeing the data, namely 30/30). The implication being that this would increase the likelihood of “type I” errors, or rather in this case, of CI’s not containing the true proportion. Choosing the sidedness of a test only after seeing the data is a practice often frowned (or worse) upon. However, it can be good practice in some cases, and the OP's scenario (observing $n$ ou of $n$ binomial counts) is one of them.
The reason that I advised to use a single sided (low bound) CI is because the observed proportion $\tilde p$ was equal to 1. So, using a double-sided CI would “waste” $\frac {\alpha} {2}$, resulting in a CI which would be wider than it needs to be to achieve $(1-\alpha)$ confidence.
Let’s use, as a for-instance, the Clopper-Pearson method of binomial CI’s. For a single sided CI, at the traditional 95% confidence level, the low bound is $0.905$, while the double-sided one is $0.8843$ (the high bound being 1). The possibility of “errors” will be maximized for the true proportion $p=.9049...$ (just below the single sided threshold). That will occur $0.0499$ times. Which is exactly what we were willing to accept.
On the other hand, if the true proportion $p=.8843$, with a double-sided test, we would make an error (exactly) 2.5% of the time. We have a 97.5% confidence CI, not the 95% confidence one we asked for.
But what if the observed counts were $n-1$ out of $n$. In such a case, the upper bound of the “exact” binomial CI will never be 1 (no matter how large $n$ is), so we no longer “waste” $\frac {\alpha} {2}$, so there is no reason to use a single sided CI (as we want the narrowest possible CI, which gives us at most $\alpha$ chance of being wrong), and I would not have made this recommendation.
But what if the true proportion was lower, but still giving sometimes samples where 30/30 was observed? Would that recommendation inflate our chance of being wrong? No, it would not. If $p<.9050$, then as we saw just above, we will be wrong at most 5% of the time (for a 95% confidence CI).
What if we used a normal approximation method. The result would be the same, if not better. E.g. the Agresti-Coul CI’s are wider than the exact CI’s, up to observing 28/30 (they start becoming narrower at 27/30). So the same applies even when using a “continuous” approximation.
The reason this works, is because of the discrete nature of the binomial. The count data can only change by increments of 1 (not by $\epsilon$ infinitesimally small).\

Chances are all your intervals are computed at level 95%; better say this explicitly (it isn't a given that all CIs are at this level).

Indeed, they are. I will edit the resoponse to make it clear.

There's a lot of good advice here, but I find it curious (and questionable) that you recommend changing the level of the test based on the outcome of the observations.  Because that's not justifiable as a general proposition, why would it be okay here?

I knew someone (maybe more than 1) would comment on this apsect of the response. My luck is that it is @whuber. So I added an edit to the answer, to explain this; take a look, and let me know.  (A reasonable answer would not fit well in a comment; bottom line, if we do not do this, we are "wasting" $\frac {\alpha} {2}$, and if we do this, we are not inflating the # of CI's which do not contain the true porportion).

Thank you for the edit, which is very informative, +1.  But I guess I didn't understand what you are trying to say by "...thus should use a single sided CI."  That seems to imply you are recommending halving $\alpha,$ but I think you're really telling us that it's a two-sided CI with an upper bound of $1,$ even if some formula indicates the upper bound exceeds $1.$

Sorry if I was unclear. I am recommending putting all the error on the low side, because we can not have an error on the high side (that is, if you observe n out of n, then you can not have any error on the high side, so switch all the error to the low side, instead of splitting in 2). So it could be interpreted as changing the level from a 2-sided test at $\alpha$ to a 2-sided test at $2*\alpha$, or changing a 2-sided $\alpha$ test into a 1-sided test at $\alpha$ . So either double $\alpha$, or keep $alpha$ and switch to a single tail. (same result)
